# Determine when a boolean changes from true to false

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a webpage that has a print button. As soon as the print button is pressed I have a function

```
function pWindowNeeded() {
    if (newPWindowNeeded == 'Y') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then I have another function that says if it is true then open a new window containing a PDF to be printed and change the newPWindowNeeded to 'N'

this all works fine.

Also when the user clicks the print window right now I have this function being run

```
function alertWindow()
{
    var w = window.open('','',' width = 200, height = 200, top = 250 , left = 500 ');
    w.document.write("Please Wait<br> Creating Document(s).<br><img src='loadingimage.gif'>");
    w.focus();
    setTimeout(function() {w.close();}, 5000);
}
```

This also works fine, the window is created and then after 5 seconds it automatically closes.

This works fine for now but what I actually need is to evaluate when pWindowNeeded returns false and when it does return false I need it to automatically close the window.

What is the most effective way to evaluate when pWindowNeeded has changed from true to false?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just check `newPWindowNeeded` again? Or set another flag?

Comment: The best way would be to fire an event when you set `pWindowNeeded` using a message bus. The poor way would be to have a `setTimeout` that runs constantly and checks the value of `pWindowNeeded`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what code changes `newPWindowNeeded` to `Y`? Seems like a strange way to trigger a window opening.

Comment: @Katana314 Could be a lot of things, a checkbox on the page? A timeout because of (or lack of) user interaction...

Comment: @JuanMendes wouldn't that have to be setInterval then?

Comment: @Joo Not necessarily, I prefer to use a `setTimeout` that calls itself when I do have to resort to polling See http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful

Comment: @JuanMendes could you give me an example of how you'd have the settimeout constantly check a value? I'm having some trouble trying to implement that right now

Answer (score 1):

The least efficient and easiest way to do it is to poll for the value using setTimeout.

```
function callbackWhenWindowNotNeeded(cb) {
    if (!pWindowNeeded()) {
        cb(); 
    } else {
        // The lower the number, the faster the feedback, but the more
        // you hog the system
        setTimeout(callbackWhenWindowNotNeeded, 100);
    }
}

function alertWindow() {
    var w = window.open('','',' width = 200, height = 200, top = 250 , left = 500 ');
    w.document.write("Please Wait<br> Creating Document(s).<br><img src='loadingimage.gif'>");
    w.focus();

    callBackWhenWindowNotNeeded(function() {
        w.close();
    });
}
```

Ideally you'd use some sort of MessageBus to prevent polling. Here's an example with a poor man's bus.

```
var MessageBus = (function(){
   var listeners = [];
   return {
    subscribe: function(cb) {
        listeners.push(cb);
    },
    fire: function(message) {
        listeners.forEach(function(listener){
            listener.call(window);
        });
    }
})();

function alertWindow() {
    var w = window.open('','',' width = 200, height = 200, top = 250 , left = 500 ');
    w.document.write("Please Wait<br> Creating Document(s).<br><img src='loadingimage.gif'>");
    w.focus();

    MessageBus.subscribe(function(message, event) {
        if (message == 'WINDOW_NOT_NEEDED') {
            w.close();
        }
    });
}

// Then wherever you set your newPWindowNeeded
newPWindowNeeded = 'N';
MessageBus.fire('WINDOW_NOT_NEEDED');
```

Comment: @JOO Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Try the `MessageBus` approach using something like http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-observer/

Comment: I'm going to try and use the MessageBus. I've got a try catch for checking if there is a popup blocker enabled and for some reason it's hitting that catch. I will get back to you with the results