# Timed for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I don't even know how to get started with this: I need a for loop that executes a `function` (say a simple `console.log()`) with a timed delay between each execution. I've been trying to do it with `setTimeout()` and it never works. If I call the function that has the loop from setTimeout, it won't work. Ideally I'd want my `for` loop to print something x times, with a couple of seconds delay between each printing. Any ideas how that might work? I've tried something like this:

```
function printStuff(){
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
console.log(i);
}
};
setTimeout(printStuff(),1000);
```

Comment: How about `setInterval()`?

Comment: Show what you have tried. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30583301/determine-when-a-boolean-changes-from-true-to-false/30583883#30583883) has an example

Comment: setInterval() or delay() if you are using jQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me you should execute `setInterval` and inside this you should increase counter. When counter reach the limit you simply clear interval.

```
var counter = 0;
var limit = 10;
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
    if (counter > limit)
    {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
    counter++;
    console.log("test"); 
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
init();

function init() {
  setTimeout(init, 2*1000); // wait 2 sec then call init again

  console.log(Date());
}
```

Or use `setInterval`:

```
// Call init after 2 sec and repeat calling it every 2. sec
setInterval(init, 2*1000);

function init() {
  console.log(Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) module.

```
var count = 0;
async.whilst(
    function () { return count < 5; },
    function (callback) {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    },
    function (err) {
        // 5 seconds have passed
    }
);
```

This way the count will be printed every second

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
function timeout(){
    setTimeout(log, 1000);
} 
function log(){
    console.log(i++);
    timeout();
}
log();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sq4v0kbf/

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`. Parameters are just the same:

```
setInterval(function () {
  // your utility code goes here
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do it. Use a wrapper function.

```
var time = 2000;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, time);
    })(i);
    time+=2000;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sort of delayed loop function with the number of iterations/times you want to run. Something like this:

```
var delayedLoop = function (n, milliseconds) {                                       
    var iteration = function (n) {                                              
        if (n > 0) {
            n--;
            console.log(n);                                             
            setTimeout(function () {                                               
                iteration(n)                                                          
            }, milliseconds);                                                              
        }                                                                        
    };                                                                         
    iteration(n);                                                               
}
delayedLoop(4, 1000);
```

You could even expand the idea and even passing a function to be executed each time.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/19x1L4he/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is simpler ([and doesn't have the fallbacks of](http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful)) than a setInterval

```js
    var limit = 10,
      counter = 0,
      delay = 1000;

    function doIt() {
      document.body.innerHTML += 'Hit counter: ' + (counter++) + '<br />';
      if (counter < limit) {
        setTimeout(doIt, delay);
      }
    }
    doIt();
```

And you can generalize it

```js
function runTimedLoop(delay, howMany, callback) {
  var index = 0;

  function iteration() {
    callback(index++);
    if (index < howMany) {
      setTimeout(iteration, delay);
    }
  }
  iteration();
}

runTimedLoop(1000, 10, function(index) {
  document.body.innerHTML += 'Hit counter: ' + (index++) + '<br />';
});
```